# How to create a Servlet Filter in Eclipse in the absence of web.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlet-filters

I am using Eclipse 3.6.2 and developing a Dynamic Web App project. I need to use a servlet filter. ( I am coming from NetBeans where web.xml would automatically created ) 
While creating this project I didn't click on Generate Deployment Descriptor and now Eclipse is not allowing me to create it. 
Is there a way to use servlet filter without web.xml ?
Please let me know if you want more info on this. 
( Creating the project anew is not an option since it is a huge setup which will take me weeks  given my work schedule )
I found no answers for this in existing questions !
Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: You can right-click WEB-INF folder, create a new xml document named web.xml;)

Comment: Or add `@ServletFilter(urlPatterns={"/myurl"}`annotation in your Filter class

Comment: Thanks Noob ! Do you mean that the second option ( @ServletFilter ) would not require the web.xml at all ?

Comment: Thanks Noob ! I found out that it does not require web.xml at all :)